# sorting dictionary values (tuples) through a calculation + condition

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How would I go about showing only the values in a setting a condition on the key portion of a sorted part as well as displaying a number calculated after the value.

I've tried

```
sorted(d, key = lambda x: (sqrt(d[x][0]*d[x][0]+d[x][1]*d[x][1])))
```

in different variations but I'm not sure how to set a condition in the same line

```
d = { 2: (4,-6) , 5: (3,2), 3: (5,9) }
```

would be an example of a dictionary and I want it to display only

```
[(3,2): whatever sqrt value, (5,9) : whatever sqrt value]
```

sorted based on `sqrt` value

I need both values to be positive and the equation is suppose to be the square root of the values together.

I'm trying to only use the `sorted` function and not import anything else... I couldn't find another thread about this one specifically so I would appreciate any help

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary. Dictionaries don't keep the elements in any order.

Comment: You can make a list of the dictionary elements, and then sort them. But sorting just reorders things, it won't filter out elements where the key function is invalid. You need to filter them out first, before sorting.

Comment: @Barmar how should I go about this then? I'm relatively new to programming and I'm required to sort it by the sqrt after the filtering all in one single return statement.

Comment: Figure it out step by step. First find out how to get a list of dictionary values. Then find out how to filter a list. The sort the list using `sorted`.

Comment: The only way you're going to learn to program is to do it, not by having someone else figure it out for you.